# React native component function promise return url onNavigationStateChange

Tags: http, react-native, webview, promise

I have a component, this component is nothing but a WebView.

I make a call to this component and I want a result back, through promises.

I have to make sure that after the WebView is loaded and running onNavigationStateChange, I have to return a Promise to return the result.

Main:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import ShortUrl from './ShortUrl';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.shortUrl
      .init('https://www.cineblog.life/?trdownload=0&trid=24045&movie=0')
      .then(uid => {
        console.log('URL: ' + uid);
      })
      .catch(err => alert('error: ' + err));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ShortUrl
          ref={r => (this.shortUrl = r)}
          style={{ width: 0, height: 0, backgroundColor: '#000' }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

ShortUrl:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, WebView } from 'react-native';

export default class ShortUrl extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      initialUrl: '',
      init: false,
      //promise:
    };
  }

  init(initialUrl) {
    this.setState({ initialUrl, init: true });
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      resolve('OK');
    });
  }

  onNavigationStateChange = navState => {
    const { initialUrl } = this.state;
    if (initialUrl !== navState.url) {
      return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(navState.url);
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { initialUrl, init } = this.state;
    if (!init) return null;
    return (
      <View>
        <WebView
          source={{
            uri: initialUrl,
          }}
          onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Link expo: [Here](https://snack.expo.io/HkKhL-Q1N)

Comment: Try to pass a funciton as a parameter and call that function like pass callback onjava.

Comment: @VolkanSahin45: could you give me an example?

Comment: Look @Milore 's answer

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully understand your question, but it seems you're simply looking for a function passed as prop to your child component. Once your promise is completed just call that function you have in prop and pass it a parameter, in order to handle it in the parent component.

In your Main:

```
[...]
  <ShortUrl
    ref={r => (this.shortUrl = r)}
    style={{ width: 0, height: 0, backgroundColor: '#000' }}
    handleResult={ resultArrivingFromChild => { // do what you want with the result }}
  />
```

In ShortUrl:

```
onNavigationStateChange = navState => {
  [...] // do what you have to do
  this.props.handleResult(resultYouWantToSendBack);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have to use the component only when the function this.shorturl.init(url) is called then the component does not need me anymore until I redo the init call. I do not know if I explained myself well.

Comment: So, probably it's me the one who doesn't understand, but... Why not just move `shorturl.init(url)...` in ShortUrl component?

Comment: What do you mean?
You know the component ShortUrl for how it is written for the moment?
I need that when I have to use it, I call it, I pass an url, which would be a short url, I need an original url.
As soon as onNavigationStateChange gives me a different url from the one I've been through, then I have to get back to where it is at that moment, so I just have to go back to url.
Then from that moment on I do not need any more, until I pass another url.